# firebase auth web error does not appear?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I try to implement Firebase auth with email and password from quickstart-js on github : https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js into my own javascript. But why my code doesn't show any error, like when user sign up using same email?

```js
btnreg.addEventListener('click', e =>{
                var email = document.getElementById('txtemail').value;
                var password = document.getElementById('txtpass').value;
                if (email.length < 4) {
                    alert('Please enter an email address.');
                    return;
                }
                if (password.length < 4) {
                    alert('Please enter a password.');
                    return;
                }
                firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
                    var errorCode = error.code;
                    var errorMessage = error.message;
                    if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
                        alert('The password is too weak.');
   
                    } else {
                        alert(errorMessage);
                        console.log(errorMessage);
                    }
                    console.log(error);
                }); 
            });
```

Comment: You have an error `console.lo(` instead of `console.log(`

Comment: even i change into `console.log(`, still can't retrive any error, i also got this code from firebase auth docs.

Comment: Did you make other modifications to the repo code? what are you seeing exactly? Is the page reloading? Is there any error in the console? is the network request succeeding?

Comment: if i use original code from repo, it will show me alert box `The email address is already in use by another account.` if i try to sign up with same email. But it's not show me alert box in my code.In repo code, it have `window.onload = function()`, but in firebase auth docs, this `function` not included. Firebase auth docs just give me `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error)` and i put any error in console. i also follow Firecast video : http://youtu.be/-OKrloDzGpU, still no error occured.

Comment: `window.onload` is needed  to add all the click handlers after the dom is loaded. Are you sure your click callback is running on click? Your click handler may not be set up correctly.

Comment: i use `btnreg.addEventListener('click` and i can register new user, but i can't get any notification. Can you give example with `window.onload` ?

Comment: The quickstart example is already available. There's not much i can add to that.

Answer (score 0):

In my test I solved using try{} catch {}

```
 try {
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      }catch(error) {
          console.log(error.code);
          console.log(error.message);

      }
```